# Within Rmarkdown how can I link to a file using an r chunk instead of in the main text

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to link to a file in an rmarkdown document but doing it using r code as the file path changes with the rest of the code and is not static (i.e. if it were static I could just include it in the main text).

Any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: Does the file path change in a predictable way? Can you show some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticked expressions in your markdown text:

`````
   ```{r}
        link_text = "Click me!"
        link_url = "http://example.com"
    ````
    For details, see [`r link_text`](`r link_url`)
`````